# On declaring optionals and non-optionals in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm confident this might be a duplicate, but I can't find any tidy and compact explanation, so here it goes.

We all know that, if we declare a variable like this

```
1> var a : String?
```

we get an optional

```
a: String? = nil
```

and if we omit the `?` we have to initialize `a` to something else than `nil` at creation time. However, if we say something like

```
2> var a : String!
```

we get

```
a: String! = nil
```

which confuses me to no ends, because I was under the assumption that that declaration meant that `a` could not be an optional. So, playing around with the REPL, I get the following bemusing results:

```
 3> a!
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

 4> a as! String
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

 5> a as! String?
$R2: String? = nil

 6> a as? String
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

 7> a as? String!
$R3: String!? = nil
```

Can someone provide some light into this?

Comment: Please read the section about `Implicit Unwrapped Optionals` in the Swift Language Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var a: String!` is what we call an *implicitly unwrapped optional*. It is an optional that may hold the value of `nil`, but the compiler does not produce any compile-time errors regarding it.

If it had a nil value, and was used, you will get a runtime error as if you would by force unwrapping a normal optional that has a `nil` value.

> Implicitly unwrapped optionals are useful when an optional’s value is
>   confirmed to exist immediately after the optional is first defined and
>   can definitely be assumed to exist at every point thereafter.

Comment: So, it's good for, say, variable properties of a class or struct that I know I'm going to initialize at some point **before** using them, right? But then why am I allowed to set them to `nil` afterwards? That would surely violate the assumption that they "exist at every point thereafter". I would expect the runtime to prevent me from doing that.

Comment: I am not sure why such a restriction does not exist. You could only hope that every person you work with knows the way to deal with them, and that they will not break tradition.

Comment: However, if such a thing is worrysome for you, the safest way is to use a normal optional coupled with an `if let` statement to unwrap it safely.

Comment: Yes, I think my problem was really on how to declare properties rather than how to unwrap optionals.